# Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I get this below error message on Blazor server app when I try to send images over 50KB

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'

I am using a richtext box and when I paste an image on it over 50KB I am getting this error. The error is happening on Blazor.server.js. This issue must be related to the data limit that can be send over web socket however even after I update this limit to larger size, I still see this issue.

This is my startup file code where I have modified the limit.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options =>
                {
                    **options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
                    options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;**
                });
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
```

The error is happening on blazer.server.js and the connection is getting dropped eachtime it is happening. Has any one faced this issue with Blazor server
[image]

Comment: summernote, my code is not picture the code in the picture is from blazer.server.js

Comment: I ran into this problem as well, but I was putting too many interactive buttons. I was able to fix it by using Virtualize instead of foreach.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have increased the size for Singal R and that fixed the issue for now but this is not a proper solution.

```
services.AddSignalR(e => {
                e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
            });
```

The proper solution is to implement your own hub between client and server and process in chunks and stick it together.

refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Why is increasing the maximumreceivemessagesize bad? Would it be ok if you knew you were never going to exceed the set size? I am experiencing the same problem trying to read an object from 'ProtectedSessionStore' in browser session storage and increasing the message size like above solves it. Are there pitfalls? thanks

Comment: It's not "bad" per se, but it doesn't fix the issue. It's like if your car is leaking gas so you install a larger gas tank, you can drive further but you are still leaking gas.