# How to pass large json to Blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, base64, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server application to display a file on the pad. File sending by a client. The client chooses the file he wants to show on the tablet.

In the application, I have a MainLayout component that contains an Await component (empty page with only one "Wait" spinner) until SignalR receives an ViewDocument event (which contains file data as base64). On this event, MainLayout should replace the Await component with the PdfViewer component.

Here is my simplifyed MainLayout component:

```
<main>
   @Body
</main>
@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        hubConnection.On("ViewDocument", (BinaryDocumentModel data) =>
        {   
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            string mimeType = MimeMapping.MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping(data.Name);

            if (mimeType.Contains("pdf"))
                Navigation.NavigateTo($"/PdfViewer/{jsonData}/", false, true);
        });
    }
}
```

Question:
I'm not sure if I'm replacing the Await component with the PdfViewer component correctly. The only way I've found is to use NavigationManager.
But using NavigateTo the only option to pass base64 to a child component is using the url parameter's (*is that right, yea?*).

Problem:
Base64 is too big to fit in the query. My application just crashes when I try to pass a json using the url parameter. *If I change the content in my data before serializing to json, everything works fine (except the empty file in the PdfViewer component).*

My thoughts:
I can either find another way to call the PdfViewer component *(then it might be possible to transfer data in another way, for example using standard [Parameter] fields)* or change some settings in the application to make such a large json acceptable *(as a url param)*.

Actually, can you advise me how to be in this situation.

Comment: Does [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323116/7687666) inspire you ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be something else entirely. The problem is that base64 contains '/' characters, which are interpreted as a route symbol.

A trivial addition of this line solved my problem:

```
string encodeData = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
...
Navigation.NavigateTo($"/PdfViewer/{encodeData}/", false, true);
```